# Undocumented AWS TAG_FILTERS_1_0

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

AWS recently introduced the new [resource-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resource-groups/index.html#cli-aws-resource-groups) API. They mention the [`TAG_FILTERS_1_0` query type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resource-groups/search-resources.html), but I can not find any documentation on how to use it - let alone an example.

I've tried all variations in

> $ aws resource-groups search-resources --resource-query "Type=TAG_FILTERS_1_0,Query=..."

but no dice.

**Bonus:** I'm trying to get all resources of a specific type (in my case lambda functions) that are tagged with a specific tag. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am working on the Resource Groups team, happy to help - apologies for not catching this question earlier. You can find some examples how a query looks like in our documentation in the ['updating Resource Group' section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/updating-resource-groups.html).

This is how you create a resource group using the CLI:

`aws resource-groups create-group --name "HelloWorld" --resource-query '{ "Type": "TAG_FILTERS_1_0", "Query": "{\"ResourceTypeFilters\":[\"AWS::AllSupported\"],\"TagFilters\":[{\"Key\":\"stackoverflow\",\"Values\":[\"heythere\"]}]}"}' --tags '{"stackoverflow": "heythere"}'`

Since the example above also tagged the resource group itself, you can check that it actually shows up in the group: `aws resource-groups list-group-resources --group-name 'HelloWorld'`

If you want to filter for one or multiple specific resource types, you just swap the `AWS::AllSupported` with the list of resource types you want to see. See [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/supported-resources.html#supported-resources-console) for a list of resources AWS Resource Groups supports.

Hope this helps, and let me know if there are any followup questions - feel free to also reach out in the AWS Forums or via support. If you just have feedback for us, you can also use the 'Feedback' button in the bottom right of the console, we constantly monitor this, too.

I will make sure we update our documentation to reflect more examples.

Comment: That's great. What's the query to get all resources?

Comment: @IronBishop Resource Groups groups your resources by a tag, or by a CloudFormation Stack - it then returns all resources with such a tag, or part of a CloudFormation Stack. Returning 'everything' in your account is not supported, unless of course you make sure everything has the same tag.

Comment: OK, and is there any API way I can look through all my resources to be sure that everything is tagged?

Answer (score 0):

I've started using the [ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.html#getResources-property) instead. It doesn't answer the question of how to use `TAG_FILTERS_1_0`, however it solves my problem.

If anyone has more input on `TAG_FILTERS_1_0` I'd be very happy to update the accepted answer!